# UILabel not displaying any message

Tags: ios, objective-c

Picture first ~~

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *textview;
}


- (IBAction)randomWords:(id)sender;


@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(IBAction)randomWords:(id)sender {
    int ran = arc4random() % 6;
    switch (ran) {
        case 0:
            textview.text = @"Cat";
            break;
        case 1:
            textview.text = @"Dog";
            break;
        case 2:
            textview.text = @"Fish";
            break;
        case 3:
            textview.text = @"Horse";
            break;
        case 4:
            textview.text = @"Bird";
            break;
        case 5:
            textview.text = @"Test";
            break; 
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

The label box I've put doesn't display any message.
Is anything wrong or anything I left?

The custom class for the Label is `UIControllerView` with StoryBoard Hello.
Can anyone help me so when they redirect to the app it will randomly generate a message.

[image]

Comment: When is called: `randomWords`?

Comment: @Larme , I don't get your statement . Please be more specific sorry and thank you in advance ^_^

Comment: Perhaps your `label` is hidden behind any view ?

Comment: When are you calling the randomWords method? Is it connected to a button because I can't see one in your picture?

Comment: @AbhishekBedi, I've checked nothing checked the class also still under UILabel.

Comment: @user3546239: have you debugged `randomWords:` method ? Is it going into it? try calling `[label bringSubviewToFront]`

Comment: @AbhishekBedi , tried no luck.
I dragged the label in the pic to the interface at ViewController.h

Comment: @user3546239: try doing afresh with simple `UILabel` class and then try custom classes.It should help.

Comment: both doesn't work also . @AbhishekBedi . What seems to be the problem..

Comment: @user3546239: What do you mean by :: *The custom class for the Label is UIControllerView with StoryBoard Hello* ???
The code is pretty straight forward and it should work unless any connection got loose or broken. There should be a dark grey circle next to the method `randomWords:`.
Also try creating the label outside {} in .H file so that you refer to as `self.label`. I know this is hit and trial sort of thing but I dont have any better idea right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont really see how is `textview` added to the main view. If through `Storyboard` you should do it like this

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UBOutlet UILabel *textview;
```

and then link this outlet to your `Storyboard` label in order to use this property.
Second solution is to create your label in `viewDidLoad` method like so:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 textview = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,self.view.frame.size.width -10,100)];
 textview.numberOfLines = 10;

 [self.view addSubview:textview];
}
```

At the moment you have a reference that doesn point to an object on your screen.
Hope this helps you to understand why your label doesn't show your text.

Comment: There's error now all the files in my .m folders return error.

instead of textview it's asking me to rename it as _textview

Comment: use `self.textview` or as suggested `_textview`

Comment: Which approach you were taking. Linking an outlet in your `Storyboard` or programmatically adding your `UILabel` to your view?

Answer (score 2):

so use this code for test :

```
  -(IBAction)randomWords:(id)sender {
    dispatch_async ( dispatch_get_global_queue ( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND ,  0 ),  ^{

           int ran = arc4random() % 6;

        dispatch_async ( dispatch_get_main_queue (),  ^ {

        switch (ran) {
            case 0:
                textview.text = @"Cat";
                break;
            case 1:
                textview.text = @"Dog";
                break;
            case 2:
                textview.text = @"Fish";
                break;
            case 3:
                textview.text = @"Horse";
                break;
            case 4:
                textview.text = @"Bird";
                break;
            case 5:
                textview.text = @"test";
                break; 
            default:
    textview.text = @"Said";
                break;
        }



        });
    });


    }
```

Comment: No luck , My controller class for the page is ViewController but for the label remain as UILabel. Correct right but still no output..

Answer (score 0):

It might be that some or all of the connections between your code and your storyboard aren't hooked up.

In your viewcontroller.h, it might be better to refer to your label like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * textview;

@end
```

You'll need to connect that label to your storyboard, and you can tell if that's so by checking that the circle to the left of the @property ...  line is filled in.

For your "randomWords" button, there would also be a circle to the left of the - (IBAction) statement.  If that's not filled in, you'll need to connect the "touch up inside" event for that button to that method.

Finally, you could also try

```
arc4random_uniform(6)
```

as a way of guaranteeing that you get a whole number from your random number generator.

Comment: There's error now all the files in my .m folders return error.

instead of textview it's asking me to rename it as _textview

Comment: I would use self.textview .  The @property directive causes XCode to create getter and setter methods for the label, and it also creates (as you mentioned) a _textview object variable.